# How to play an audio file when a button is clicked in WP8?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am tring to play an audio file on a button click function.I have tried this code , but it doesn't work.How to play the audio file in code behind?

```
    public static List<string> audiofiles = new List<string>();
    public static string sound1 = (new Uri("/Assets/Audio/baby-crying-01.wav", UriKind.Relative)).ToString();
    public static string sound2 = (new Uri("/Assets/Audio/baby-crying-02.wav", UriKind.Relative)).ToString();
    public static string sound3 = (new Uri("/Assets/Audio/baby-crying-03.wav", UriKind.Relative)).ToString();
    public static string sound4 = (new Uri("/Assets/Audio/baby-crying-04.wav", UriKind.Relative)).ToString();

    public static string[] sounds_list = new string[4];

    private void Practice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
           this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(music);
            audiofiles.Add(sound1);
            audiofiles.Add(sound2);
            audiofiles.Add(sound3);
            audiofiles.Add(sound4);

            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                sounds_list = audiofiles.ToArray();                                
                music.Source = new Uri(sounds_list[i], UriKind.Relative);
                music.Play();
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **MediaElement** to play sound in Windows Phone.
Steps:

1. Create New Project.
2. Drop `MediaElement`
3. After this set its `name` property to `mycontrol`. Change source property according to your file.

   ```
   <MediaElement x:Name="mycontrol" Source="/1.mp3" AutoPlay="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="103" Margin="98,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" />
   ```
4. To play the music file automatically as the page opens you can set the AutoPlay property of `MediaElement` to true. By default the `AutoPlay` property is true.
5. You can control media playback by using the Play, Pause, and Stop methods of a `MediaElement` object.
   Add three buttons to the `MainPage.xaml` having the `Content` property value **play, pause and stop**.
6. The code for click event handlers of these buttons is given below.

   ```
   private void play_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       mycontrol.Play();            
   }

   //pause the audio file
   private void pause_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       mycontrol.Pause();
   }

   //stop the audio file
   private void stop_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      mycontrol.Stop();          
   }
   ```
7. Done.

Comment: what kind of error you are getting.. can you post your error here.

Comment: No error has displayed ,but the audio doesn't play.

Comment: First you have to add your audio file to assets then you have to change source of this example with your media file.